# Restlet Reference decoding "#" sign

Tags: java, web-services, restlet

I have setup a URI as below:

```
router.attach("/pmap/campaign/{campaign}/staffCat/{staffCat}/isp/{isp}", PMAPResource.class);
```

In the PMAPResource.class I have the following code:

```
public Representation represent()
{
    String campaignID   = (String) this.getRequestAttributes().get("campaign");
    String staffCat     = Reference.decode((String) this.getRequestAttributes().get("staffCat"));
    String ispID        = (String) this.getRequestAttributes().get("isp");
}
```

The staffCat field is manual input from user, it can be anything. Some examples are:

```
BAA2(A)
BAB1#(A)
BA B1
```

It works for most cases until it hits the # sign where it returns `404 Not Found` error. Console dump shows the following `/fwd-PMAP/pmap/campaign/1/staffCat/BAB1`.

What should I do in order to read the "#" so I can get `BAB1#(A)` as it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#` has special meaning in a URL. It must be escaped.

There are actually many special characters in URLs, so you should always escape arbitrary text when building a URL in the client.

In this particular case, the correct URL sent by the client would be something like:

`/fwd-PMAP/pmap/campaign/1/staffCat/BAB1%23(A)/isp/XXX`

Again, this is a problem that needs to be fixed on the client. The server will decode the `%23` for you.

Comment: Thank you for the respond. I were trying to find ways to get around the # issue without extra work from the client but looks like that's the only way. I will advise the client accordingly.